# File upload : Controller \"CreateMediaObjectActionController\" does neither exist as service nor as class

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'am trying to use api-platfotm and VichUploaderBundle to upload images but I got an error. Has somebody get this problem before ?

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "detail": "Controller \"CreateMediaObjectActionController\" does neither exist as service nor as class",
}
```

[image: Here i'am uploading an image in order to test my confiduration]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. It was caused by missing "use" statement for action class inside entity class where the item operation class was defined.

In you case check if you have 
use \whatever is your namespace for this\CreateMediaObjectActionController
in entity used by media_objects route (src\Entity\MediaObjects ??).

It solved for me an issue with "Controller "XYZ" does neither exist as service nor as class" message but there is no warranty in your case it's exactly the same reason.